# Converting uint8_t* to char* for use with QIODevice

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, io, buffer

I am modifying the [Qt Audio Output example](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/multimedia-audiooutput.html) as follows:

- I have access to an audio mixer API from a third party.
- The method to read the data from this mixer is `void AudioMixer::ReadData(uint8_t *stream, uint32_t len);`
- The function I am changing to output this data in the example is the `qint64 Generator::readData(char *data, qint64 len)`

If my understanding is correct, I should be able to operate the `QIODevice` in a push mode by overriding the `Generator::readData` method to call the `AudioMixer::ReadData` method and cast the `uint8_t*` used by the `AudioMixer` to a `char*` for use with the `QIODevice`.

Am I correct in thinking this is somehow possible? If so, can someone advise on how to do the cast? If not, can you offer an explanation on how to output the `uint8_t*` using a `QIODevice`?

For the sake of completeness, the methods are:

```
void AudioMixer::ReadData(uint8_t *stream, uint32_t len)
{   
    if(buffer.GetMaximumReadSize() < len)
    {
        memset(stream, 0, len);
    }
    else
    {
        buffer.Read(stream, len);
    }
}
```

and

```
qint64 Generator::readData(char *data, qint64 len)
{
    qint64 total = 0;
    while (len - total > 0) {
        const qint64 chunk = qMin((m_buffer.size() - m_pos), len - total);
        memcpy(data + total, m_buffer.constData() + m_pos, chunk);
        m_pos = (m_pos + chunk) % m_buffer.size();
        total += chunk;

        // Need to call AudioMixer::readData in here
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: uint8_t *a; char *b = (char *)a;

Comment: Is it really as simple as that? Are there not potential problems because a `char` is essentially signed?

Comment: The signedness (in lack of a better word) should only be relevant if you are going to do bitshift operations. If shifting to the right unsigned variables will always be filled with 0s, signed variables with ones or zeroes depending on the value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no native type to represent a "byte" in C++, only `char` that is guaranteed to hold exactly one byte.  There are different opinions whether a byte type to represent raw binary data should be signed or not, so some use `unsigned char` (`uint8_t`) and others use plain `char`.  In the end, it does not really matter, since you usually don't perform arithmetic operations on binary data, but just read and interpret it.

Therefore, you can just use a type cast to convert between different binary data representations.  Since this is C++, you should use `reinterpret_cast` (in favor of C-style casts):

```
char* dst = reinterpret_cast<char*>(/* your uint8_t* expression */);
```

Whether to use `reinterpret_cast` or C-style casts is obviously disputed.  Bjarne Stroustrup, the creator of C++, would [certainly advocate for `reinterpret_cast`](http://www.stroustrup.com/devXinterview.html), but others don't like it, and that's OK.

Comment: Stop pushing reinterpret_cast whether it is needed or not. reinterp.... is a lot of typing, and in this case is a totally equivalent to an old-good C cast. There are cases where it really matters in run-time (i.e. vtable offsets) or helps type safety (unintentional buggy type casting). But really, you have to understand it rather than having a silly rule saying - type more just because it looks more unlike C.

Comment: "should use" No you shouldn't. You "should" use simplest correct solution. Which is C-style cast in this case.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` is there for a reason, and many C++ coding guidelines out there clearly state that you should prefer new-style casts over C-style casts.   I don't know why you are making such a fuss about that here.  Yes, it's lengthy (Bjarne Stroustoup said it's "an ugly notation for an ugly operation"), but come on, it's not that much to type.

Comment: @VladLazarenko -- just to be clear: it was not my intention to criticize your comment, just to answer the question.  Whether to use a C-style or new-style cast here is not the point.  The answer to the question is: just use a type cast.  I do not favor `reinterpret_cast` because it "looks unlike C", but because it's just the C++-way to do it (Stroustrup even said he would "like to ban C-style casts" alltogether if he could, see http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/devXinterview.html).